# Ionic compound having highest solubility in water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility, solutions, liquids

Which ionic compound has highest solubility in water? I can find CsBr having highest solubility with 1230 g/L at 25 °C.

Note: compounds like ethanol are soluble to any extent in water, but they are covalent, not ionic.

Comment: It would be interesting to split in the two cases of molar solubility and mass solubility, though the latter is easier to find data on directly.

Comment: I could be cheeky and add Ionic Liquids to the list, which often mix with water at any ratio. Maybe clarify that you are talking about solids at standard conditions.

Comment: @TAR86 Darn, I was just a bit late with my edit! I'll leave that sidenote in my answer anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Caesium salts are unapologetically ionic, and they typically have quite high mass solubilities in many solvents, including water.

Assuming organic ions are allowed, [caesium acetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium_acetate) ($\ce{H3CCO2^-Cs+}$) in particular has a remarkably high solubility of 9451 g/kg water at −2.5 °C, increasing to 13 455 g/L water at 88.5 °C.

Caesium formate ($\ce{HCO2^-Cs+}$) is also quite soluble, with a solubility of 4880 g/kg water at 20 °C, resulting in 2.56 L of solution with a density of 2.297 g/mL ([reference, .docx file](https://www.nicnas.gov.au/__data/assets/word_doc/0004/19822/NA811FR.docx)). However, its solubility increases much faster with increasing temperature ([*J. Chem. Soc., Trans.*, **1922**, *121*, 1837-1843](https://pubs.rsc.org/-/content/articlelanding/1922/ct/ct9222101837/unauth#!divAbstract)). At 100 °C, it reaches an outstanding value of **20 071 g/kg water**! That's 11.6 molal, or roughly 20-25 mol/L assuming the density doesn't change too much. This saturated solution is 67.7% cesium formate by number of moles, which means more than two caesium ions and two formate ions per molecule of water.

I believe I have read somewhere that caesium formate is the record holder for highest mass solubility in water (evidently only at high temperatures). If this is not true, then I can scarcely believe it will be topped by much.

Tangentially, Ivan mentions [Clerici's solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerici_solution), which is actually a mixture of thallium(I) formate and thallium(I) malonate. The mixture doesn't count (though the individual components are quite soluble themselves), but it interesting to analyse. Apparently 300 g of each compound will dissolve in 40 g of water without saturating it room temperature ([ref](http://rruff.info/doclib/am/vol24/AM24_116.pdf)), giving a lower bound to their combined solubility of 15 000 g/kg water. This value rises with heating, and is the only way I can see to beat the mass solubility of caesium formate.

For further entertainment, I recommend these two solubility tables with a large number of entries ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table), [2](http://www.sciencemadness.org/smwiki/index.php/Solubility#Solubility_of_chemicals_in_water)). The second one can be ordered by solubility at different temperatures. It's interesting to see the variety of cations and anions which can be combined to display extreme mass solubility.

**Edit**: If [room-temperature ionic liquids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_liquid#Room_temperature_varieties) are allowed, then it is quite likely some of them are miscible with water in any proportion, which is effectively "infinite solubility in water". Something as simple as [ethylammonium nitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylammonium_nitrate) ($\ce{C2H5NH3+NO3-}$) may suffice.

Comment: If they are ionic, the state of matter does not matter.  +1.

Answer (score 9):

The following data is compiled from [1, pp. 4-44, 5-167]:

**Table 1.** Selected solubility values of the inorganic compounds with significant ionic character at $25~\mathrm{^\circ C}$.
$$
\begin{array}{lc}
\hline
\text{Formula} & \text{Solubility in water}/\pu{g L-1}\\
\hline
\ce{CsF} & 5730\\
\ce{SbF3} & 4920\\
\ce{LiClO3} & 4587\\
\ce{Pb(ClO4)2} & 4405\\
\ce{ZnCl2} & 4080\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Solubility of [antimony(III) trichloride $\ce{SbCl3}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimony_trichloride) is $9870~\mathrm{g~L^{-1}}$ at $25~\mathrm{^\circ C}$, but technically it's not an ionic compound.

#### References

1. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data.; **2017**; Vol. 97.

Comment: I've seen antimony trichloride before in tables, but it is apparently very easily hydrolysed, so perhaps it shouldn't be counted either way.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Yep, you are right, and the same probably goes for $\ce{ZnCl2}$. I also omitted $\ce{ZnBr2}$ for similar reason (and it's covalency, too).

Answer (score 8):

There is not going to be a single definitive answer, primarily because of a wide gray zone surrounding the domain of ionic compounds. Besides, as Nikolau noted, the question is ambiguous.

If you want mass concentration, then look at $\ce{InI3}$ which claims a whopping [$13100~\mathrm{g/L}$](http://chemister.ru/Database/properties-en.php?dbid=1&id=5904). Pity that it is probably ionic in name only, judging by the solubility in non-polar solvents. Well, then look at those mentioned by **andselisk**, though the ionic nature of some of them is also debatable, and then at the thallium formate (a component of Clerici solution) with $\sim5000~\mathrm{g/L}$.

If you want molar concentration, then the question is *still* ambiguous (are we looking at molarity or molality?), and the pretty strong contenders are $\ce{NaOH}$, $\ce{BeF2}$, $\ce{LiClO3}$.

So it goes.

Comment: True, $\ce{InI3}$ is *weird*, but it's definitely not ionic and the reference for the solubility value dates back to 1940s or something:)

Answer (score 3):

We can do better than that.  [Ammonium nitrate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_nitrate) = 1500 g/L at 20°C.